# Accessing an element in a vector of struct c++ using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

Hi I'm new to c++ and wanted to ask a questions on how to access an element of struct inside a vector using pointers.
lets say I have a struct:

```
struct pets{    //struct of pets
string name;
int age;
}

int main() {
pets a = {bolt, 2};
pets b = {crash, 3};

vector<pets> x;
x.push_back(a);
x.push_back(b);
vector<person> *ptr = &x;
???

}
```

using the pointer ptr to the vector x how would I be able to access the first the age of the the first element stored in my vector of pets?
I am aware its easier to use

```
x[0].age
```

but I wanted to acces the elements member using a pointer to a vector of struct.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference it first:

```
ptr[0][0].age;
// ^^^ make sure you don't use >0 for the first one
```

or

```
(*ptr)[0].age;
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/mUsrHv).